# How to split an SSH address + path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, ssh, ip-address

A Python 3 function receives an SSH address like `user@132.243.32.14:/random/file/path`. I want to access this file with the `paramiko` lib, which needs the username, IP address, and file path separately.

How can I split this address into these 3 parts, knowing that the input will sometimes omit the username ?

Comment: Why not use the `SSHClient()` to do this?

Comment: How can it ? I tried to pass the full address to `SSHClient.connect()` and I got an error. Don't remember which, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.partition` and `rpartition` will do what you want:

```
def ssh_splitter(ssh_connect_string):
    user_host, _, path = ssh_connect_string.partition(':')
    user, _, host = user_host.rpartition('@')
    return user, host, path

print(ssh_splitter('user@132.243.32.14:/random/file/path'))
print(ssh_splitter('132.243.32.14:/random/file/path'))
```

gives:

```
('user', '132.243.32.14', '/random/file/path')
('', '132.243.32.14', '/random/file/path')
```

Answer (score -3):

## use

not set(p).isdisjoint(set("0123456789$,")) where p is the SSH.